# How to change cart location on mobile?

Tags: bigcartel

I'm using the foundry theme. On desktop the cart is in the top right hand corner on every page, even when you scroll. On mobile the cart is at the very bottom of the page, and many people have had trouble finding it. Is there any way I can put the cart on mobile in the same location as the cart on desktop?